# Application variables issue

Tags: zend-framework, web, webserver

Have two instances of same application(as Dev/PROD) running under Virtual Hosts in a Dedicated server with two different domain names using Plesk Panel for management. I know it doesn't make sense Dev/PROD on one instance but DEV is used hardly 5-10% of time and we can't afford to have one more server. But the issue is Application variables used in PROD domain are being overridden by the variable in DEV. Is there any way to config webserver or Zend framework to see the two instances as separate spaces?

Comment: What do you mean with Variables in this case?

Comment: I have created a variable called APPLICATION_URL with first domain and the same variable reused by second domain. Which I don't want to? Hope I'm clear

Comment: Where is this variable defined?

Comment: The dev version and the production version are in different directories, correct?

Comment: yes. Variable is defined in config.inc.php under application\configs\ directory in both.  There are two directories named httpdocs\ and other one is one docroot\ folder which uses different domains to point to.

Comment: Do you define an APPLICATION_ENV = production/development in your virtual host settings ?

Comment: No, I set that variables in Application.ini under the same configs folder but not on virtual host settings.

Comment: Did you remember to configure your DNS to use the separate vhosts. I use a single server on my local machine with a number of projects on vhosts. I also have to make sure I change my hosts file so that DNS will work.

Comment: Yes, I have made the necessary DNS changes and the first page is redirecting properly to the site, but since the application code is written to read APPLICATION_URL variable and generates URL's to the first instance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good solution that might be at help in your case.
[Keep application.ini in version control without conflicting](http://www.iostream.eu/keeping-application-ini-in-version-control-without-conflicting/)

Comment: Well, its close but the application is still not finding the modified ini file. Any ideas?